# Cache Data and Update Observable

Tags: rxjs, observable

I'm trying to respond from a service in my Angular application with the Cached data but also trigger a request to update the when subscribed to. I have tried

```
cache : Observable<any> = this.http.get<any>(ENDPOINT).pipe(shareReplay(1));

getData() : Observable<any>{
  return this.cache;
}
```

The problem appears to be that the `shareReplay` blocks further subscriptions.  I'm pretty sure I can do this by creating `Observables` with logic built in but was hoping there may be a streamlined way with the standard operators.

EDIT

The below code provides the desired result, There may be a more elegant way however

```
cache : ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);

getData() : Observable<any>{
  this.http.get<any>(ENDPOINT).pipe(first()).subscribe(x=>cache.next(x));
  return this.cache
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `shareReplay` more used to prevent repeated requests, you can use `ReplaySubject` or `BehaviorSubject`.

---Edit ---

I'm sorry I mistook your intentions, `shareReplay` should be able to cache data, the only problem is that new requests cannot be regenerated.